# Password protection of part of Jekyll generated site

Tags: passwords, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have a category that I want to protect using a password. I googled and found out some solutions to protect the whole site, but that's not what I want. I was wondering if there is a way to do that. Appreciate any suggestion.

One of the scenarios is, the category, say called personal, is located in the navigation bar, when people click this button, they are asked to enter password to visit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://cloudcannon.com/ and create private content that is password protect.

Comment: Really? I know you can password protect a whole website at once with CloudCannon (if you use their hosting), but the OP wants to password protect only one category.

Comment: Cofounder of CloudCannon here. Yes you password protect a particular directory, have a look at the docs - https://docs.cloudcannon.com/authentication/custom-routes/

Comment: Thanks Mike! Great news!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using regular hosting you can use a .htaccess file. If you host on github you can create a form that redirects to a filename that equals your password. Make sure your repo is private and you block search engines.